# Como faço para somar um array?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde é assim a minha duvida é imaginando que tenhos estas variaveis :

```
var powerRangers = ['Red', 'Black', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];
```

e quando eu uso o for ( por exemplo )

```
for (var i = 0; i < powerRangers.length; i++) {
     console.log([i]+":"+powerRangers);
}
```

O objetivo e sair :
0: Red'
1:black'
2:Yellow'

**... E sempre assim ... Help**

E o que sai na real é :

0:Red,Black,Yellow,Pink,Blue
1:Red,Black,Yellow,Pink,Blue
2:Red,Black,Yellow,Pink,Blue
3:Red,Black,Yellow,Pink,Blue
4:Red,Black,Yellow,Pink,Blue

Comment: Isso não é somar um `array`, você quer concatenar um iterador numérico com elemento de um `array` em uma `string`.

Comment: Ahhh Obrigado !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você acessar o índice do seu `array`, dessa forma:

```
 console.log([i]+":"+powerRangers[i]);
```

Comment: Meu deus muito obrigado ! :D

Comment: Neste caso o codigo correto seria :

for (var i = 0; i < powerRangers.length; i++) {
     console.log(i+":"+powerRangers[i]);
}